# How can call the Alfresco REST API using Json String?

Tags: json, jsp, alfresco

Please provide me some references to call **WebScripts** in alfresco remotely using JSON..
Alfresco has some default Webscripts ,I need to invoke these Webscripts in different Application remotely...

Comment: Can you clarify what you need? You can hit any Alfresco web script remotely over HTTP. Web scripts that require authentication will need either the credentials in the header or a ticket passed via alf_ticket. So are you looking for a list of web scripts or a description of the JSON that is expected or are you looking for help writing your own web scripts?

Comment: Description of the JSON that is expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documentation that I know of at the present time that documents all web scripts that expect JSON to be posted along with a schema that defines the expected JSON. Honestly, we haven't done a good job identifying which out-of-the-box URLs are actually public. Some are there just for the Share application's use and could change without warning.

With that said, you can go to http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/index and see a list of web scripts. And if you drill down into the web script (click on the web script's ID), you can see the source code for the JavaScript controller or, if the web script is implemented in Java, you can see the full class name that implements it. You can then inspect the source to see what it is expecting.

Another way to do it is to use Firebug or your browser's developer console to watch the network calls that go from your browser to the repository tier. Many of these calls include JSON being posted to repository tier web scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're referring to getting a webscript to respond with a json, there are a few steps.
1. Create a webscript, and possibly set json the default format (in the webscript definition file, i.e. mywebscript.get.desc.xml, add a tag 
`<format default="json">argument</format>`

1. Create a JSON controller too, ie. mywebscript.get.json.js. This script can do two things:

a) get json parameter (if you sent a json in): `if (json.has('myparam')) myVar = json.get('myparam');`

b) provide some data to the model, ie. `model.docs = companyhome.children`

1. Your webscript also needs to format this json for json response, i.e. mywebscript.get.json.ftl would look something like this:

   { "docs": [

   ```
   <#list docs as doc> {

     "name": "${doc.name}",

     "prop": "${doc.properties["mymodel:myprop"]}"

   } <#if doc_has_next>,</#if>

   </#list>
   ```

   ]

   }